# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4 and ...ApiException: 5000: Application needs OAuth consent from the user

Tags: google-fit

i'm trying to connect to google fit and exchange the health data with its from my app.
Here my code:

```
            if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(
                    GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext()),
                    new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BLOOD_GLUCOSE_READ_WRITE)
            )) {
                GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestEmail()
                        .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BLOOD_GLUCOSE_READ_WRITE))
                        .build();
                GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this.getContext(), gso);

            
                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }

            if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(
                    GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext()),
                    new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BLOOD_GLUCOSE_READ_WRITE)
            ))
            {
                Log.e("GOOGLE_FIT", "no permission");

                GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                        this, 
                        GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                        GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext()),
                        new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BLOOD_GLUCOSE_READ_WRITE)
                );


            } else {

                accessGoogleFit();
            }
```

and the method access GoogleFit():

```
private void accessGoogleFit() {
    final  String LOG_TAG="i am here";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .build();


    Fitness.getHistoryClient(this.getContext(), GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this.getActivity()))
            .readData(readRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSuccess()");
                }


            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onFailure()", e);
                }
            })
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onComplete()");
                }
            });
}
```

When execute the i recive this error:

> onFailure()
> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 5000: Application needs OAuth consent from the user
> at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:4)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zai.zaf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:2)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zak.onComplete(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:6)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:176)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:135)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.fitness.zzae.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness@@20.0.0:3)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.fitness.zzdp.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness@@20.0.0:13)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.fitness.zzbf.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness@@20.0.0:11)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.fitness.zza.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness@@20.0.0:13)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)

I followed the step in https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started.

Plese help me and say me what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you to evreyone!

Comment: It looks like you're requesting `Scopes.FITNESS_BLOOD_GLUCOSE_READ_WRITE`, and then trying to read `DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA`. You would need `Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ` if you want to read steps.